# Как бы СПП, но после идёт сочинительный союз

Tags: пунктуация, спп, сложное-предложение, ссп, трудности

> О, и я, конечно, уверен, что ты уже знаешь, но он нам не очень-то и нравился.

Знаю, предложения читается с трудом; но меня интересует кое-что другое:

[О, и я конечно, уверен (в чём?), что ты уже знаешь (что?), *но* он нам не очень-то и нравился].

Меня интересует *что ты уже знаешь*, ибо оно требует обязательное продолжение, потому что СПП, но после идёт сочинительный союз *но*, который относится к ССП, где предложения равноправны. По-другому я не могу сформировать вопрос.

Как быть?

Comment: Поставить двоеточие и не париться?

О, и я, конечно, уверен, что ты уже знаешь (это), но (все таки еще раз скажу): он нам не очень-то и нравился.

Comment: Да я уже так и сделал, только чуть-чуть по-другому: «О, и я, конечно, уверен, что ты уже знаешь — он нам не очень-то и нравится» (можно двоеточие вместо тире). Но меня интересует именно этот случай: здесь, по правилам, обязательно должна продолжаться мысль, но идёт соченительный союз; разговорно звучит предложения ±, а вот, по моим текущим знаниям, оно неверно.

Comment: Да тут нет противоречия. И вы правы, и автор прав, и разговорно все звучит. Просто пропущено (опущено) легко восстанавливаемое указательное местоимение-заглушка "это": О, и я, конечно, уверен, что ты уже знаешь это, но: он нам не очень-то и нравился. Это так называемое неполное предложение. Обычное дело для разговора. Другое дело - неполные и некорректные предложения, вот с ними надо бороться.